# Save state on a input on submit Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I would like to save an input status to the submit of my form. I explain myself by my code:

This is the code to my view:

```
<div class="input-group mb-3 input-spinner">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <button id="qtt" class="btn btn-light increment-quantity" type="button" data-direction="1"> + </button>
  </div>
  <input class="form-control quantity-selectors-container" data-min="1" data-max="0" type="text" id="realQuantity" name="quantity" value="1">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button id="qttt" class="btn btn-light decrement-quantity" type="button" data-direction="-1" disabled="disabled"> − </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way in Javascript to save the value of the input that has the class quantity-selector-container when I change it with the keyboard?

Comment: You can achieve that using jQuery `change` function

Comment: in jquery, you can get the value of the input using `$('.quantity-selectors-container').val();`

Comment: Please explain your use case in more detail. Save can be done numerous ways depending on what you need to accomplish at a higher level and how you need to access the stored data

Comment: For one, you ask about `quantity-selector-container`, but your class is in fact `quantity-selectors-container`. Are you asking because you've made an attempt yourself, but didn't notice your own typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like mentioned in my comment, I am unaware whether you're asking this question because you don't know how to do it, or whether you attempted the issue, but overlooked your own typo in the class name.

In your question you are asking for a change event on the class:

`quantity-selector-container`

when in fact, your class is called:

`quantity-selectors-container`

Note the *"s"* in the *"selectors"* part. This is at least assuming that the markup you provided is correct.

Now, if you are unaware how to achieve this, and the typo wasn't what kept you back, then what you'll need is to add an `EventListener` to your selector, in this case the class `quantity-selectors-container`.

**HTML Example:**

```
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input class="form-control quantity-selectors-container" type="number" data-min="1" data-max="0" id="realQuantity" name="quantity" value="1" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**Vanilla JS Example:**

```
const inputElement = document.querySelector('.quantity-selectors-container');
inputElement.addEventListener("change", function() {
    let inputValue = this.value;
  alert(inputValue);
});
```

Vanilla JS Codepen Example [here](https://codepen.io/mbacode/pen/PoZzxam).

**jQuery Example:**

```
$('.quantity-selectors-container').on("change", function(){
    let inputValue = $(this).val();
    alert(inputValue);
});
```

jQuery Codepen Example [here](https://codepen.io/mbacode/pen/QWyEJZr).

**Snippet Example:**

```js
const inputElement = document.querySelector('.quantity-selectors-container');
inputElement.addEventListener("change", function() {
 let inputValue = this.value;
 alert(inputValue);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input class="form-control quantity-selectors-container" type="number" data-min="1" data-max="0" id="realQuantity" name="quantity" value="1" />
  </div>
</div>
```